# No me toma event.target.value en el formulario reactivo

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un formulario reactivo para usar dos select dependientes, categoria y subcategorias. al seleccionar una categoria me debe mostrar las subcategorias dentro de la misma.

tengo dos modelos de datos:

```
export interface categoria{
    idcategoria:number,
    nombrecategoria:string
}
```

y subcategoria

```
export interface subcategoria{
    idsubcategoria:number,
    nombresubcategoria:string
}
```

Luego tengo el html de mi componente:

```
<section>
         
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">

      <mat-form-field >
          <mat-select #categoria placeholder="Categoria" [(ngModel)]="selcat.idcategoria" 
          (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" name="categoria"  >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let cat of categorias" value="{{cat.idcategoria}}" >
              {{cat.nombrecategoria}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
       
            <mat-form-field >
                <mat-select #subcategoria placeholder="Subcategoria" name="subcategoria">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let subcat of lsts" [value]="subcat.id_subcategoria">
                    {{subcat.nombre_subcategoria}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>     
            </section>
```

Pero me dice:

**error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
(change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" name="categoria"  >**

Y no se a que puede deberse. Por ultimo muestro mi archivo .ts:

```
@Component({

    selector: 'app-articulo',
    templateUrl: './articulo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./articulo.component.scss']
  })
  export class ArticuloComponent implements OnInit {
   public selcat:categoria={idcategoria:0,nombrecategoria:''};
   public categorias!:categoria[];
   public subcategorias!:subcategoria[];
   public value2:any;
    public lst!: any;
    public lstc!: any;
    public lsts!:any;
    public filtroForm:any;

    public columnas : string[]=["nombreProducto","precio","stock","categoria","subcategoria","marca",'actions'];
    constructor(
       
        private apicategoria : ApicategoriaService,
        private apisubcategoria : ApisubcategoriaService,
        private apiArticulo : ApiarticuloService,
        private dialog:MatDialog,
        public snackBar:MatSnackBar,
      ) {
     
        }
        @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort!: MatSort;
        @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
       
      
        ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     
        }
      
      
        getcategoria(){

            this.apicategoria.getCategorias().subscribe(resp=>{

            this.categorias = resp.data;

          });
          
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {
            

            this.getArticulos();
            this.getcategoria();
            this.getsubcategorias(1);
           
          }
          getsubcategorias(idc:number) {
          
            this.apisubcategoria.getsubcategorias().subscribe(resp=>{
           
            return resp.data.filter((subcategoria: any)=>idc==resp.data.idsubcategoria)
            });
           
          }
         
        getArticulos(){

              this.apiArticulo.getArticulos().subscribe(resp=>{

              this.lst = new MatTableDataSource<articulo>(resp.data);

              this.lst.sortingDataAccessor = (item:any, property:any) => {
                return item[property].toLocaleLowerCase();
              };
              this.lst.sort = this.sort;
              this.lst.paginator = this.paginator;
        
            });
            
          }
          onSelect(id:any):void{
              console.log(id);
          }
  }
```

como veran accedo a los servicios para obtener las categorias y subcategorias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sé que la documentación está algo confusa al respecto.

Yo lo manejo así:

```
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Select the categories</ng-template>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-select placeholder="Select Item" multiple formControlName="firstCtrl"
                      (selectionChange)="changeCategory($event.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">
              {{category}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
```

Como verás mando `$event.value`, basado en la sección [MatSelectChange](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectChange) de la documentación de angular material.

Esto porque intuyo que `MatOptionSelectionChange` es hija de `MatSelectChange`.

Del lado componente recibirás el tipo que sea tu atributo `value` de tus options:

```
changeCategory(event: string[]) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
  this.categorySelection = event;
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, me muestra "Object Object" en las opciones, si coloco {{category.nombreCategoria}} aparece en blanco.. Igual el idcategoria me lo retorna ya es un avance. me faltaria poder filtrar las subcategorias por ese idCategoria.

Comment: por eso puse el json.stringify para que saque la representación. Espero te sea útil.

Comment: ok..muchas gracias amigo!